# App for Specific Requirements - ASP.NET MVC 4, EF 5, Database First, Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-5

I have done some deep google-ing but apparently not deep enough. I am looking for an example application out on any code repository that has the following specs. Mad props to anyone who can point me in the right direction because I usually do not find myself hunting for snarks and/or unicorns.

- .NET 4.5
- EF 5
- Database First
- Web API Integration
- Other Requirements - minimum of 3 application layers, DI

Again, thanks to anyone who has or knows where this little ditty lives.

( ;

Comment: I've been looking for the same, no luck so far. But I did come across [Project Silk](http://silk.codeplex.com/). Its focused more on the client side, but there's some really good documentation and  I think its still a valuable resource to look at.

Comment: Start from the source: [ASP.Net](http://www.asp.net/). You'll find them there and it should hopefully be apparent how you'd combine all (or some) of the above. Site contains tutorials. downloadable projects, etc.

Comment: @EdSF - Yeah. Will do man. I figured as much. ( ;

Comment: There are few projects like Account at glance application, single page application by john papa they are using the latest technologies like mvc 4, entity framework, web api but both are using code first approach.  You can google it!

Comment: I've been intending to build a stub project on exactly this stack of technologies for a while now. If you find one, please let us know - and if you decide to build one, please let ME know. Perhaps we can put it up on GitHub or something, and start getting a little community around it. It would be a great offering to the development community.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently trying to come up with a similar setup and here's what I can recommend:

1. Go back to asp.net and look at the various principles involved (ASP .NET API, EF etc) and see how you can come up with a mashup. This seems to work for me thus far.
2. I just came across [this.](http://jaydata.org/blog/prepare-an-asp.net-web-api-project-with-ef-database) They seem to achieve what you may be struggling with.

Happy Coding.